# Changing QML Object value from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I created a QML class like

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4

Rectangle {
    width: 80
    height: 200
    property double myVal: 15

    Timer {
        running: true
        repeat: true
        interval: 1
        onTriggered: gauge.value = myVal
    }

    Gauge {
        objectName: "gauge"
        id: gauge
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10

        value: myVal
        Behavior on value {
            NumberAnimation {
                duration: 1000
            }
        }

        style: GaugeStyle {
            valueBar: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 16
                color: Qt.rgba(gauge.value / gauge.maximumValue, 0, 1 - gauge.value / gauge.maximumValue, 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to change value from my c++ file. To do this, I created a method which is setDataToGauge() and this method is like

```
void MainWindow::setDataToGauge(double newVal){

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl::fromLocalFile("gauge.qml"));
    QObject object = component.create();
    QObject *myGauge = object->findChild<QObject*>("gauge");

    if(myGauge){
        myGauge->setProperty("value",newVal);
        qDebug() << myGauge->property("value");

    }

}
```

this. However, it doesn't change the value of gauge. I tried different methods but it couldn't find the solution. When I drop

```
    Behavior on value {
        NumberAnimation {
            duration: 1000
        }
    }
```

this part from QML file value is changing but view of gauge is not changing. 
Also, I am adding to full code of my c++ file

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QtQuickWidgets/QQuickWidget>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QObject>

QObject *object;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    m_serial(new QSerialPort(this))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->gaugeWidget->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("gauge.qml"));
    ui->gaugeWidget->setUpdatesEnabled(true);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl::fromLocalFile("gauge.qml"));
    object = component.create();

    setDataToGauge(60.0);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::setDataToGauge(double newVal){

    QObject *myGauge = object->findChild<QObject*>("gauge");

    if(myGauge){
        QQmlProperty::write(myGauge, "value", newVal);
        qDebug() << myGauge->property("value");
}
```

}

What is the problem in there?

Comment: I think that this code should not show any .qml, are you sure it's the only place where you use the .qml?

Comment: yes i am sure i put it to a widget in my main window.

Comment: I just checked it and it shows nothing, please show a [mcve]

Comment: I created a widget and i added it to widget by the way ui->gaugeWidget->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("gauge.qml"));

Comment: Edit your question and add it there.

Comment: Okay i added it

Comment: see my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your attempt of solution you are creating another gauge, and that gauge is not shown because the `QQmlApplicationEngine` is a local variable that will be deleted when it finishes executing, in addition `QQmlApplicationEngine` expects a `Window` or `ApplicationWindow`, not an `Item` like `Rectangle`.

On the other hand it is advisable to use a `qresource` to store the .qml because otherwise you will have to copy them every time you compile the side of your executable.

It is also not recommended to access QML objects from C ++, it is better to export a C ++ object to QML using `setContextProperty()`.

A simple solution is to create a signal, the signal is connected through `Connections`::

***.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    void setDataToGauge(double newVal);
signals:
    void dataGaugeChanged(double dataToGauge); // signal
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

***.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->gaugeWidget->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("MainWindow", this);
    ui->gaugeWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/gauge.qml"));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::setDataToGauge(double newVal){
    emit dataGaugeChanged(newVal);
}
```

**gauge.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4

Rectangle {
    width: 80
    height: 200

    Gauge {
        id: gauge
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10

        Behavior on value {
            NumberAnimation {
                duration: 1000
            }
        }

        style: GaugeStyle {
            valueBar: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 16
                color: Qt.rgba(gauge.value / gauge.maximumValue, 0, 1 - gauge.value / gauge.maximumValue, 1)
            }
        }
    }
    Connections{
        target: MainWindow
        onDataGaugeChanged: gauge.value = dataToGauge
    }
}
```

---

Another option is to create a `Q_PROPERTY` and make a binding:

***.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(double dataGauge READ dataGauge WRITE setDataGauge NOTIFY dataGaugeChanged)

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    double dataGauge() const;
    void setDataGauge(double dataGauge);
signals:
    void dataGaugeChanged();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    double mDataGauge;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

***.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->gaugeWidget->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("MainWindow", this);
    ui->gaugeWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/gauge.qml"));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

double MainWindow::dataGauge() const
{
    return mDataGauge;
}

void MainWindow::setDataGauge(double dataGauge)
{
    if(mDataGauge == dataGauge)
        return;
    mDataGauge = dataGauge;
    emit dataGaugeChanged();
}
```

***.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4

Rectangle {
    width: 80
    height: 200

    Gauge {
        id: gauge
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
        value: MainWindow.dataGauge // binding

        Behavior on value {
            NumberAnimation {
                duration: 1000
            }
        }

        style: GaugeStyle {
            valueBar: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 16
                color: Qt.rgba(gauge.value / gauge.maximumValue, 0, 1 - gauge.value / gauge.maximumValue, 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>Both solutions can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/51824477).</sup>

Comment: Firstly thank you for you answer but in first solution there is a mistake that i couldn't solve. There are error messages which are  QML Connections: Cannot assign to non-existent property "onDataGaugeChanged" and ReferenceError: mainwindow is not defined. What is the source of this error messages?

Comment: Also, it gives reference error for the second solution which is ReferenceError: MainWindow is not defined. I am sorry about my question i am just new with QT

Comment: @HilalKöktürk have used `ui->gaugeWidget->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("MainWindow", this);`?

Comment: @HilalKöktürk 
Have you tried my examples that are in the link ?, first try them, and when you understand them, implement them in your own code

Comment: @HilalKöktürk 
If someone gives you an answer, analyze it before you want to implement it and cross-examine this way, you save us time. :)